# getting a list of values which contain objects which have an id field of x

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Sorry - I bet this has been asked lots of times before, but I can't find the answer to my question.

I have two entity framework classes, Companies, and Users. I want to produce a list of companies which have the user allocated to them.

```
public class FIGcompany
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }

 }

public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FIGcompany> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

The Linq I am using, I have got as far as:

```
 var t = db.Companies
            .Any(q => q.Users.Contains(q.Users.
```

can anyone help me finish it off, I am struggling to get the UserId field from users to do a comparison.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using lazy loading or eager loading..?? If eager loading then you can use include() to get this done.

Comment: `q.Users.Contains(q.Users.` is redundant.. it will always be true either way - I think you want to use `q.Users.Contains(db.Users...)`. Mmn.. do you want to get the companies that have a specific user, but you don't have the user id?

Comment: sorry - I need to be clearer - lets say for example, the logged in user has the userId of 47 and I want to create a list of all the companies this user has been allocated to.

Comment: First off `Any` will return a `bool` indicating that the predicate was true for one of your companies.  You need to use `Where` to get back the companies that match your predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return companies which have at least one allocated user:

```
var companiesWithUsers = db.Companies.Where(c => c.Users.Any());
```

If you need companies which have user with some **id**, then:

```
var companiesForUser = db.Companies.Where(c => c.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why query Companies, when you have UserID?

```
db.Users.First(user => user.UserId == givenId).Companies;
```